# can't change user-limit on calendar api via google developer console

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, developer-console

I had some issues in the production environment with error "403: User Rate Limit Exceeded" when using the google calendar api. The [error description page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors) suggested to change the user limit in the developer console.

Logging into the developer console i did see a user limit of '5 requests/second/user' as seen in

[image: this image]

After clicking on the pencil, i saw

[image: this image]

Because i was unable to put in any number, i ended up deleting the content of the box and saving it. After that the api was unavailable due to 'not enabled'.

To try and restore the previous state of the api, i disabled it in the developer console and re-enabled it. This does not have the indended behaviour:

[image]

So now i'm stuck with an api with no global quota and a zero user limit, which can not be changed (no pencil to be seen anywhere).

I need to get this service restored asap.

Note: this behaviour is reproduceable on any new project by adding the google calendar api and following my steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a quota increase request with explanation in the comment to google. 
They responded today:

```
Hello xxxxx, 

Thanks for reporting the configuration error you're seeing for your app (Project ID xxxxx) when setting your "per-user" limit to 0. 

I've increased your "per-user" limit back to 5, you should see this amount in your console now. 

Apologies for any inconvenience you may have experienced. 

Regards,
Frank
Developer Platform
```

In the developer console i can see the quotas and the limit of 5 requests/sec/user. The service is also back up.

Thanks Frank from the Google Developer Platform.

Comment: You should be able to change it now.

Comment: Indeed i can! 'Maximum' is now changed from '-1' to '1000000'. Thanks Luc.